# jQuery + Python Response Data

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

The following jQuery will call a Python script. The Python script is able to receive the post data. However, the jQuery is unable to receive the response by the Python script.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#dd").blur(function(){
    $.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/validation/trial/",
    {
      dd:document.getElementById("dd").value
    },
    function(data){
      alert("Data: " + data);
    });
  });
});
```

The following is the python script:

```
def trial(request):
    dd = request.POST.get('dd')
    print dd
    return HttpResponse(dd)
```

Comment: You have to return your value to send it to the JQuery

Comment: I used a HttpResponse but it did not work too.

Comment: Have you tried just a straight return?

Comment: Do you get an error in the javascript console? If you set a `Content-Type` of json, you should also return json: `import json; dd = json.dumps({'yourkey': dd}); return ...`

Comment: I used both json and non-json. All did not work.

Comment: Straight return does not work too.

Answer (score 1):

In Django, `print`ing things does not send them back to the client; you need to actually return a response. See [the Django tutorial part 3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/#write-your-first-view):

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the polls index.")
```

Comment: Please update your question with your new code (show your whole view please)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#dd").blur(function(){
    $.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/validation/trial/",
    {
      dd:document.getElementById("dd").value
    },
    function(data){ // <-- note that the variable name is "data"
      alert("Data: " + data);
    });
  });
});
```

The returned variable in the Python script needs to have the same variable name.

```
def trial(request):
    data = request.POST.get('dd')
    return HttpResponse(data)
```